# Ошибка при синхронизации команд discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытаюсь синхронизировать команды, но выдаётся ошибка.
Код:

```py
class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.all())
        self.synced = False
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(guild_id))
            self.synced = True
        log(f"Successful launch of the {self.user}")
```

Ошибка:

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandSyncFailure: Failed to upload commands to Discord (HTTP status 400, error code 30034)
```

Comment: Официальная документация api discord

Вот инфа о коде ошибки 30034 - Max number of daily application command creates has been reached (200)